# Force OpenCurrentDatabase to use Access 2003

Tags: ms-access

I'm running VBA in Access 2003, but when I use OpenCurrentDatabase to open another DB, it's opening in Access 2007 which I don't want to happen. Short of un-installing 2007 I'm not sure how to force it to use 2003 - can anybody help?

Comment: Easier? or Clearer? Hard to say...

Comment: Why would you be using late binding to open another Access database? For that matter, are you sure you need to automate another instance of Access from within Access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the option in Windows explorer to default Access 2003 for the file type ".mdb"

Comment: It's possible to specify with late binding the exact version of Access that's used with CreateObject(). I don't know the exact syntax (it's something like CreateObject("Access.12.Application"), but you'd have to look it up), but if you want to get around the problem of having to have the correctly registered version in order for your code to work, you can investigate this option.